# Persisting dynamically loaded user controls in view state

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, viewstate

I have a simple user control containing two text boxes which I am adding to placeholder on Button Click event. I am storing the number(count) of clicks in View state and running a loop using count to create all previously added user control. I am also adding IDs to each User control (appending "UC" and count). I have also checked in view source the ids are same each time they are created. I have another button which basically does an post back. I have EnableViewState enabled ="true" in all controlls all the way up to Page Level.
My problem is that User Input does not persist on postback. please advice. Should this not be happening automatically for me?

Comment: Please rephrase or clarify your question.  Provide code examples if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

I've encountered minor problems with it on a web farm, but for simple deployments its use is pretty straightforward.  (Comes with source code, and the web farm glitch is a pretty simple fix.)

Comment: Could you share the minor problems you encountered, and maybe even the fix? it'd be nice to know in advance. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your dynamic controls in the Page_PreInit event rather than Page_Load or in a Click event handler. That way, they'll be there before ViewState, and then your posted values are applied.

I thinks what is happening is that you are creating your controls during the click event handler which happens AFTER ViewState and PostBack have been applied. This means your controls will be created empty each time.

Comment: This is a very good point.  Even if the control is recreated in init on later postbacks, if it was first created during a click / change event handler it will mess up the control's viewstate tracking.